# How can you get Rspec to connect to Chromedriver on CircleCI?

Tags: selenium, rspec, circleci

I have setup Chromedriver locally to work with my Rails stack and to be the browser-executor for my RSpec tests.

Locally it runs fine but on CircleCI it's failing with the following error:

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError:
unable to connect to chromedriver 127.0.0.1:9515
# ./spec/spec_helper.rb:190:in `raise_with_helpfulness'
# ./spec/integration/navigate_site_pages_spec.rb:77:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

This happens with all specs that require a browser. Chromedriver and chrome are both definitely installed on circle using their own proprietary orb and I've SSH'd in to confirm that. But I still get this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a LOT of debugging this eventually turned out to be an issue with the CircleCI cache. I don't know why particular elements were being cached but changing the cache-key allowed the whole thing to work.

Comment: Can you share the circleci's config.yml ? I want to see how have you added chrome driver ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this -

gem uninstall chromedriver-helper

remove it from rbenv shims (which chromedriver for that)

Download directly http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html

plug chromedriver somewhere on the $PATH (I just plopped in ~/bin)

Comment: Hi Rakesh, it's not a problem with installing it locally, it's a problem with installing it on CircleCI. It is already confirmed installed there as I can verify it with SSH - it's just not connecting.